Which posets arise from closed, transitive relations?
This a follow up question of Chain components and posets.
Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $R\subset X^2$ a closed, transitive relation. Denote by $|R|=\{x\in X: xR x\}$ the diagonal of $R$.
The relation $x\sim y \Leftrightarrow x R y\  \land\ y R x $ is an equivalence relation on $|R|$ and the equivalence classes form a poset if we say that $A\le_R B$ for $A,B\in |R|/_{\sim}$, if $x Ry$ for some $x\in A$ and $y\in B$.
Is there an explicit characterization of the posets that can/cannot arise in this way given the metric space $X$?

It is easy to see that the posets $(U,\le)$ that can arise in this way are exactly such that for all $u$ and $v$ in $U$
$$u\le v\ \&\ v\le u\implies u=v. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
That is, any poset can arise this way.

Indeed, if for some $A$ and $B$ in $|R|/_{\sim}$ we have $A\le_R B\le_R A$, then for some $a,a_1$ in $A$ and some $b,b_1$ in $B$ we have
$$aRb \quad \text{and}\quad  bRb_1\!Ra_1\!Ra,$$
so that $aRb$ and, by the transitivity, $bRa$, so that $a\sim b$. So, $A\le_R B\le_R A$ implies $A=B$.
Vice versa, if \eqref{1} holds for a poset $(U,\le)$, let $R$ be $\le$. Then for any $u$ and $v$ in $U$ we have $u\sim v$ iff $u=v$ and hence $(|R|/_{\sim},\le_R)$ coincides with $(U,\le)$.

The conditions that $X$ is a compact metric space and $R$ is closed play no role here.

I'm sorry, I'm confused. Apart from other things, there has to be some connection with the properties of $X$. A trivial instance: if $X$ is finite, no infinite poset can arise, for instance. So how can it be that "any" poset can arise?

Also, I don't think that you can get a countable dense total order if $X$ is uncountable, if $R$ is closed.

@MarcoFarotti : Did you mean to assume that $X$ is fixed? From your "arise in this way" that would be hardly possible to guess. If you did mean that, you should have said "arise in this way given the metric space $X$".

Also, do not use $\mathcal R$ where $R$ will certainly do.

Yes, you're right. I edited the question, thank you.
